# Change brightness automatically on Sony Vaio laptop running Xubuntu

Tags: sony-vaio, xubuntu, brightness

Currently my Sony Vaio doesn't let Xubuntu work with its <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> brightness hotkeys. So I am using a manual script to change brightness every time I log in. It is:

```
echo 700 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

However, pages 2 and 3 of [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1854688&page=2) has someone concocting an automated script to change brightness automatically.

Would someone be kind enough to read that thing and post a good solution here?

Comment: Are you having a problem with those instructions? If so, which specific part?

Comment: @user55325 How to edit the rclocalhost file? Then how to make Xubuntu/grub run my script at startup? And why is the user TOZ in that thread creating a background process?

I just need a answer to make the brightness change script permanent.

Comment: If that's all you want to do, you could just add that script to your session startup preferences in Xfce. That would run it automatically when you log in. Alternately, you could add it on system startup either using `rc.local`, or possibly `.xsessionrc`.